# WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: for Move File keyword

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I m trying to move a file from Local Drive to Sharedrive in the network using ROBOTFramework, `Move File` keyword of `Operating System` Library has been used for it. Code worked in local and file was moved successfully however the same script through Jenkins Job is not working and throwing an error -

`"WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: u'\\\\varv5089\\kbs_uat\\KBSDS\\EE\\Member\\839',`

but no file is existed in the drive with that name..I kept the checkpoint for this verification and it was through.

Note:Jenkins is executing this script on Windows based VM, Sharedrive has been mapped to that VM, I ran the same script in the VM from local(through  CMD) and script worked fine.
Tried Copy File Keyword, but same issue.

```
*** Settings ***    
Library    OperatingSystem   
*** Variables ***    
${Member_834File_Destination}=   /varv5089/kbs_uat/KBSDS/EE/Member/839/IN    
${source_1}=        C://jenkins/workspace/OMMS_E2E_VM/Test_Data    
${Member_834_EDIFile}=    test_984.txt    

*** Keywords ***    

834_File_ASLocation    
   log    this Keyword places file in a AS location    
   Sleep    10s       
   Set Global Variable       ${Member_834File_Source}       
 ${source_1.strip()}/${Member_834_EDIFile}    
   OperatingSystem.File Should Not Exist   ${Member_834File_Destination}/${Member_834_EDIFile}
   log      ${Member_834File_Source}
   log      ${Member_834File_Destination}
   Move File    ${Member_834File_Source}    ${Member_834File_Destination}
   #Move File    ${Member_834File_Source}    ${Member_834File_Destination}/${Member_834_EDIFile}
   #Copy File    ${Member_834File_Source}    ${Member_834File_Destination}
```